# Including subdirectories in static routing for Bottle.py web framework

Tags: python, rest, twitter-bootstrap, static-linking, bottle

I'm trying to use a bootstrap themed site with a lot of vendor plugins, and use bottle.py for a web server with a few API services built in.

I was wondering, if for static routing, is there anyway to call all the subdirectories in the routing request? I want to do something like this (instead of creating a seperate routing path for each subdir)

```
 @route('/vendors/*/<filename>')
 def vendors__static(filename):
     return static_file(filename, root='./vendors/*/')
```

Is this at all possible? Is there a lookup time cost involved? Thanks!

Comment: How are you planning on returning multiple files to the client?  `return *` doesn't make sense; maybe you want to concatenate the files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bottle does support globbing the URI path; see [the `:path` filter](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#wildcard-filters).  Here's a complete example based on your original code:

```
from bottle import Bottle, route, static_file, response

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/vendors/<vendor_path:path>/<filename>')
def vendors__static(vendor_path, filename):
    vendors = vendor_path.split('/')
    responses = []
    for vendor in vendors:
        # you read the file here and insert its contents
        responses.append('<contents of ./vendors/{}/{} go here>'.format(vendor, filename))
    response.content_type = 'text/plain'
    return '\n'.join(responses)

app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

Then, a call to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/vendors/v1/v2/v3/myfile` produces:

```
<contents of ./vendors/v1/myfile go here>
<contents of ./vendors/v2/myfile go here>
<contents of ./vendors/v3/myfile go here>
```

---

As an aside: `static_file` returns to the client the contents of *one* file.  You'll need to think about how you intend to "return" multiple files to the client.  Perhaps you can concatenate their contents (as in my example above)?  In any case, this is a separate question from the Bottle routing so I'll leave it at that.